# display few elements only for a particular user, not able to do it properly

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

it is showing error stating that not able to read the property "style".
i have seen many codes in similar way. i am not able to find the error.

```
function login()
{
 
  var email = document.getElementById("email_field").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password_field").value;
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then(user => {
    
    console.log(user);
  
    alert("Welcome " +email);
    
    window.location.href = "Home.html";
    if (email = "***@gmail.com"){
      document.getElementById("gameurl").style.display="block";
      document.getElementById("gameimg").style.display="block";
      document.getElementById("gamename").style.display="block";
    }else{
      document.getElementById("gameurl").style.display="none";
      document.getElementById("gameimg").style.display="none";
      document.getElementById("gamename").style.display="none";
    }
 
  }).catch(function(error) {
    
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    window.alert("Error : " + errorMessage);
 });
}
```

Comment: It seems like you might have multiple errors. I tried to point one out below. I think you'll have to paste your HTML if you want complete help with your issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement is bad. You need to use `==` or `===`, but the one equals-sign means you're *setting* the variable, not comparing it.

Comment: i think that's not the problem, even if I change it, its showing an extra error email not defined with cannot read property style of null

Comment: That's definitely a problem, did you read my comment above? You have two or more problems on the page. If you want to fix the one you describe above, then you need to post your HTML here. Otherwise, nobody can help you fix this -- it's not enough information.

Comment: which html page should I share ? login page or home page html ?after signing in ,for a particular user I wanna display few things. Kindly help me out in solving the issue.

Comment: You have serious problems with your javascript here. You can't go to another page called `Home.html` and add an if-else statement after you change the location. You have to add the if-else clause to the top of `Home.html`. You can't run javascript on one page that affects DOM IDs on a different page. Javascript only works on the current page.